# What if I don't want a title?

Tags: culture

(I see a lot of jobs)

- sr this
- jr that
- thing

And I don't want to commit.  I want to learn it all.  I come with 7 years experience in 2-3 heavy fields of IT - but with a passion.

How do I search for a job culture where I can be exposed to multiple things and be expected to deliver?  What if I never want to be the boss or the lead?  What if I just like learning quickly and prefer it that way?  How do I keep moving with respect?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40383/discussion-on-question-by-gloomy-penguin-what-if-i-dont-want-a-title).

Answer (score 4):

Jobs need titles even if it's just 'General Assistant'.

But in answer to the body of your question, Startups and Small companies are your best option. They tend to have multiple jobs for IT to do rather than only specialists and they do expect you to deliver.

Comment: what specialties go through the worst wear?  I'm in it to live

Comment: Worst wear? Most useful?

Comment: http://humbleapostrophe.com/spelling-question-is-it-ware-and-tare-or-wear-and-tear/  ... what's the hardest thing I could possible subject myself to?

Comment: No idea, reincarnation perhaps?